# php+ajax file uploader, cannot get data from POST

Tags: php, jquery

So the html code i have:

```
<form id="loginIMGForm">            
<input type="file" name="file" id="loginIMG" />
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submitloginIMG" />
</form>

<div id="loginIMGStatus">Select an image and upload.</div>
```

and then PHP code i have:

```
<?php

$imageinfo = getimagesize($_FILES['loginIMGForm']['tmp_name']);

if($imageinfo['mime'] != 'image/gif' && $imageinfo['mime'] != 'image/jpeg') {
    echo "Sorry, we only accept GIF and JPEG images\n";
    exit;
}

$uploaddir = 'uploads/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['loginIMGForm']['name']);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['loginIMGForm']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
} else {
    echo "File uploading failed.\n";
}
?>
```

and jquery is:

```
    $('#loginIMGForm').submit(function() {
        // 'this' refers to the current submitted form
        var str = $(this).serialize();
        alert(str);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "modules/upload.php",
            data: str,
            success: function(msg){
                $("#loginIMGStatus").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings){
                    if(msg == 'OK'){ result = 'Login Image is updated'; }
                    else{ result = msg; }

                    $(this).html(result);
                });

            }

        });

        return false;
    }); 

I did debuging using alert, the data is empty. What did I do wrong.
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you calling `ajaxComplete`?

Just do this instead:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "modules/upload.php",
        data: str,
        success: function(msg){
           var result;
           if(msg == 'OK'){ result = 'Login Image is updated'; }
                else{ result = msg; }

                $(this).html(result);
            });

        }

    });
```

Also, when you say the data is empty, do you mean when you call `alert` or the `html` component?

**Edit** You can't use `serialize` on a `file`.  It isn't supported and doesn't really make sense.  See [this page](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/2656).  Also, although it wasn't an issue yet, I do suspect you're going to have problems with calling `ajaxComplete`.  The `success` parameter already handles calling your function when the ajax request completes.  I'm not really sure what will happen with your code.

Comment: when i called alert the data is empty. so i dont think the issue is from .ajaxComplete part.

Comment: ahha. I didnt know we can't use serialize on a file. Thanks for the link and info. Thanks Chris.